# Obj-C - Using data outside of AFNetworking Block

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using the below code to grab data, and self.neighbourData populates. That said, if I want to use the data returned inside this block anywhere else in my ViewController, self.neighbourData is returned NULL (unless of course, I'm using it to populate a tableView and I'm able to refresh the tableView once the data is done loading). What's the best way to get my data out of self.neighbourData somewhere else in my ViewDidLoad? I'm stumped. I simply want to display data inside a string elsewhere in my viewDidLoad - e.g.:

> NSString *test = self.neighbourData[@"name"];

**See code below:**

**ViewController.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *neighbourData;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

     NSMutableDictionary *viewParams5 = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        [viewParams5 setValue:@"u000" forKey:@"view_name"];
        [DIOSView viewGet:viewParams5 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


            self.neighbourData = [responseObject mutableCopy];


            [self.tableView reloadData];


        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

"somewhere else" must be inside the `success` blocks (or called from there), because that's the only place where `self.neighbourData` has a value.

Answer (score 0):

Going to start off with the original code to serve as a reference here:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

     NSMutableDictionary *viewParams5 = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        [viewParams5 setValue:@"u000" forKey:@"view_name"];
        [DIOSView viewGet:viewParams5 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


            self.neighbourData = [responseObject mutableCopy];


            [self.tableView reloadData];


        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }];

}
```

Per your question, you would like access to the output of the `success` block outside of the function (for example, a follow up call after the block call here

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
     NSMutableDictionary *viewParams5 = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        [viewParams5 setValue:@"u000" forKey:@"view_name"];
```

This approach has a few problems though.

First, your desired data is the result of an asynchronous call. A simple example:

1. `NSMutableDictionary *viewParams5 = [NSMutableDictionary new];` is called
2. Now you call your block. This is an async call, so it goes off and does its thing while **not** blocking anything after it
3. Some other work is now performed. Since the result of step 2 is free to run at its own pace, step 3 can go and do its own thing without the need to wait

The issue here is that step 3 could not even get access to the data you want because at this point, there likely is no data to get. There are a variety of tolerable to outright bad things you could do to make things wait, but I'm not even going to cover those.

> This is all to say that you cannot reliably expect the data you want
>   to even exist until some unknown point in time.

The next issue is scope. Your result does not exist until the `success` block completes, at which point you currently use this line:
`self.neighbourData = [responseObject mutableCopy];`

Currently, you are calling that line **immediately** after the data becomes available. Afterwards, you reload the tableView, but then no further work is done inside of this code block:

```
[DIOSView viewGet:viewParams5 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // THE DATA EXISTS...
    self.neighbourData = [responseObject mutableCopy];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    // ... AND NOW THE DATA IS GONE!
}
```

Because of how scoping works here, the data only exists for the brief window between the comments I wrote.

All of this is to say that what you are currently doing is the best you can do given what you desire to do.